# Is there a VS Code extension to highlight HTML Parser Errors

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I would like to visually see mismatched HTML tags which, for instance, prevent the Prettier formatter from running successfully and thus blocking automatic formatting without any obvious reason why.

I found this issue https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/55479 which was closed suggesting that it is better served by an extension.

I couldn't find such an extension or setting. Does anyone know of one?

I tried installing:

- Highlight Matching Tag, which helps but only if I select the tag with my cursor and then also notice the lack of a small yellow underline anywhere else on my page. That is to say, not really that helpful for this. But good extension nonetheless.

I found a lot of extensions for various formatters and auto-completions. I'm looking for a visual way to see mismatched HTML tags.

Comment: I opened another issue with Microsoft to see if they know an answer or will invest in implementing a solution https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/170831

Comment: On the Github issue linked above, a representative from Microsoft recommended the VSCode extenstion HTMLHint: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HTMLHint.vscode-htmlhint This extension has filled my need for highlighting mismatched tags. However, I believe this question doesn't fit with Stack Overflow's guidelines ("Questions asking us to recommend an ... off-site resource are off-topic"). Perhaps a post could be made at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ instead?